# Why does my javafx imageview distort the way my gif is played

Tags: java, javafx, gif

I am trying to use a gif as a background for my javafx sidebar, the gif shows and plays but seems to only repeat the first few frames even though it has a lot more.

I've tried both setting the imageview via the fxml as well as in code, it is both the same.

This is the fxml for anyone wanting to reproduce https://pastebin.com/SUV8Lan2 and this is the gif https://www.sendspace.com/file/1hpxs5
This is the way I configured the imageview:

```xml
<ImageView fx:id="backgroundFlow" fitHeight="580.0" fitWidth="250.0" pickOnBounds="true" smooth="false">
     <image>
        <Image url="@../gif/flow.gif" />
     </image>
</ImageView>
```

I expected the gif to be fully shown like this https://gyazo.com/4a2cb29f5bf95ae45c7e4c3006638bac instead I get this https://gyazo.com/8db0207787744a4c40266ae1928d34f9

Comment: I can reproduce this in JavaFX 11 and 12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in JavaFX.  The image displays correctly in Swing, so as a workaround, I would use a [SwingNode](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html):

```
SwingNode imageNode = new SwingNode();

URL url = new URL(urlSpec);
EventQueue.invokeAndWait(() -> {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
    JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(icon);
    icon.setImageObserver(imageLabel);
    imageNode.setContent(imageLabel);
});
```

The `EventQueue.invokeAndWait` is necessary, due to threading requirements for Swing objects.  (JavaFX has the same requirement;  both must execute in a dedicated thread.  [The SwingNode.setContent method is a rare exception.](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.swing/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html#setContent%28javax.swing.JComponent%29))